# Making a range into a list in Python

Tags: python, list, input, while-loop, range

I am attempting to write some programming and I seem to be having some difficulties. I want to make a certain range into a list, and then take user's input and check if it is in the range. Here is what I have so far:

```
lower = 1
upper = 10

range_list = list(range(lower, upper +1))
user_input = input()
while user_input in range_list:
    print('foo')
else:
    print('fee')
```

Currently, if I input a number that theoretically should be in the range (say, 5), it prints 'fee' rather than 'foo'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to make a range into a list? In any case, your list contains only `int` objects, but `input` always returns a `str` object, and `int` objects will never equal `str` objects

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm a bit of a newbie to Python, sorry! In that case, how could I make it so that my user can only input int objects then?

Comment: ```user_input = int(input())``` -- use this to convert the input to an int

Comment: You can convert the user input into an `int` object.

Comment: Thank you @Sushil ! Is there a way I could preform validation for that then so that my program does not crash, but still allows me to check if the input is in the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first convert the input to int, otherwise str '5' will not match in 5. So try instead:

```
lower = 1
upper = 10

range_list = list(range(lower, upper +1))
user_input = int(input())
while user_input in range_list:
    print('foo')
else:
    print('fee')
```

To validate, inside a try..except:

```
try:
  user_input = int(input())
except ValueError:
  # Input not int, do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to define the "lower" variable. The reason your code outputs 'fee' is because you need to convert your input into integer like so:

```
upper = 10
lower = 0
range_list = list(range(lower, upper +1))
user_input = input()
while int(user_input) in range_list:
    print('foo')
else:
    print('fee')
```

even so, your program will output an infinite loop. you have to give a stopping clause and asks for input at the start/end of each loop

```
upper = 10
lower = 0
range_list = list(range(lower, upper +1))
user_input = ''
while user_input!='-1':
  user_input = input()
  if int(user_input) in range_list:
    print('foo')
  else:
    print('fee')
```